# Is it possible to have a pop up menu with tab item clicked in android?

Tags: android

I have five tabs , 4th one is for messages , I want when the user clicks on it first see a popup menu with last 10 messages displayed by a list view then by clicking on anyone of them the clicked message will be opened. but now I want to make a pop up menu when message tab clicked , I know its possible with action bar , and with simple button, ,but here I want to have a pop up menu instead of Activity, is that possible?

Comment: Have you looked at the `Dialog` class? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html

Comment: I know how to make a popup menu with button clicked , but I want to have a popup menu while clicking on tab item